# PostgreSQL SQL FOUND_ROWS SHOW TABLES

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to change this SQL to PostgreSQL:

1- `$result = $this->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS found');`

2- `$result = $this->query('SHOW TABLES');`

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on this question? What do you mean you want to change SQL to Postgres? Postgres uses SQL. Do you mean SQL Server or some specific dialect of SQL?

Comment: "*Change SQL to PostgreSQL*" doesn't make sense. Postgres does use SQL.

Comment: SQL : 
$result = $this->query('SHOW TABLES');

Postgres:
 $result = this->query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.$tablename WHERE table_schema = 'public'");

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the equivalent sql code from `MySQL` to `PostgreSQL`:

1. I think there no direct statement/function of [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function%5Ffound-rows), but you can of course get it using a function for example.
2. To get the list of tables on postgreSQL similar to [`SHOW TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html) of MySQL, you can use:

   SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables